# Extract A Solution File From WSS

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss

I'm trying to figure out how to extract a solution file .wsp file from a SharePoint server. Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a small console application and access the solutions using the SPFarm.Local.Solutions property. Include the Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration namespace and use the following code snippet to download the solution file:

```
SPSolutionCollection solutions = SPFarm.Local.Solutions;

foreach (SPSolution solution in solutions)
{
    SPPersistedFile wspFile = solution.SolutionFile;
    wspFile.SaveAs("c:\\Temp\\Solutions\\" + solution.Name);
}
```

You need to make sure that your output directory exists before calling the SaveAs() method. If it does not exists an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Solutions on a farm by using the [SPFarm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.aspx).[Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.local.aspx).[Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.solutions.aspx) property.  I'm not sure if you can retrieve the underlying file though.  That's where I'd start.